# C++ Crash after looping though items from a custom List

Tags: c++

I've been working on a little project (basically, a Minecraft clone, but in C++), because I was bored and wanted to find out how good am I in C++ and OpenGL.

I have a file `List.h`, which is basically a custom C#-like list. It's basically a template class. Then I have a `Chunk` class, that basically generates blocks based on position of the chunk and it's size.

I have a list of `Chunk`s called `chunks` (with only one `Chunk` in it just for testing), then I loop through the `List`, and for each `Chunk` I loop through a list of blocks in that chunk, and then Render the block. The problem is this crashes. When I don't have the list, and try to loop through the blocks in that chunk and render them, it works okay and there is no problem. Only when I add the `chunks` list and loop through it, then it crashes.

Here is my `MainGameLoop`:

```
List<Chunk> chunks = List<Chunk>();
chunks.Add(Chunk(4, glm::vec3(0.0f)));

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(display.window)) {
    renderer.Prepare();
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chunks.At(i).blocks.size; j++) {
            renderer.Render(chunks.At(i).blocks.At(j));
        }
    }
    renderer.Clear();
}
```

List.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class List {
public:
    int size;

    List() {
        ptr = new T[65536];
        size = 0;
    }

    void Add(T a) {
        ptr[size] = a;
        size++;
    }

    T At(int index) {
        if (index < size) {
            return ptr[index];
        }
    }

    T* ToArray() {
        T* ret = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ret[i] = ptr[i];
        }
        return ret;
    }

private:
    T *ptr;
};
```

Chunk.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "../libs.h"
#include "../Blocks/Block.h"

class Chunk {
public:
    List<Block> blocks;

    Chunk(int size, glm::vec3 position);
    Chunk() = default;

private:
    int size;
    glm::vec3 position;
};
```

Chunk.cpp:

```
#include "Chunk.h"

Chunk::Chunk(int size, glm::vec3 position) {
    this->size = size;
    this->position = position;

    for (int x = -size; x < size; x++) {
        for (int z = -size; z < size; z++) {
            blocks.Add(Block(glm::vec3(x, 0.0f, z), glm::vec3(0.0f), 1.0f));
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If my Main Game Loop is like this, everything works (without changes to any other file):

```
Chunk chunk(4, glm::vec3(0.0f));
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(display.window)) {
    renderer.Prepare();
    for (int i = 0; i < chunk.blocks.size; i++) {
        renderer.Render(chunk.blocks.At(i));
    }
    renderer.Clear();
}
```

When I try to run the program (or build it and then run the `.exe` file separately), it just freezes my entire computer, and I have to restart it.

I know that it's not really well-written, the `List` class was mainly copied from the Internet (`Add`, `At` and `ToArray` are all my own functions), and the whole project is currently in beta. I'm just trying to make the basics of simple world generation, and after that I will start making everything more optimized.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. I forgot that `std::vector` exists and created my own List class because I needed an array that is not static (So I can add elements into it at any moment) I will use that and probably delete the `List.h` file since I won't need it anymore. Again thanks for the responses.

Comment: You probably need to use a debugger.

Comment: That's a lot of code, yet it's not a [mre]. Please make it into one.

Comment: I question why you are using this `List` class versus a `std::vector`. You look to be allocating 64 K  Blocks and don't appear to propery free such blocks leaking memory. Also your class violates the rule of 3/5/0. Not sure how big a Block is.

Comment: It's not really a list in the C++ data structures way. It's just a weird array class. Idiomatic C++ `.at()` functions throw an exception if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Your `At` function not only creates needless copies, it also invokes *undefined behavior*  if `index >= size` (due to lacking `return`) - you'd be better off using a library container if you don't have experience writing your own

Comment: I'd definitely use an `std::vector` here instead of your `List`. If you wanted to reserve all the memory for your `std::vector` up front (like you are for your `List` you can use the following: `std::vector<int> vec{ }; vec.reserve( 65536 );`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but this might be PART of your problem:

```
T At(int index) {
    if (index < size) {
        return ptr[index];
    }
}
```

You should:

- Throw an exception if index < 0 or index >= size. That's probably not the problem.
- Return a reference:

  T & At(int index) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
  // throw an exception
  }
  return ptr[index];
  }

Otherwise what you're doing is copying the data a LOT. Every call to At copies the data. I don't know what your renderer does if you feed it temporary objects.

This might not actually fix anything, but it would be an improvement.